# sbt-native-packager: Set systemd service file to non config

Tags: sbt-native-packager

I have sbt-native-packager 1.3.6 and generate rpm packet. In spec file i see:

`%config(noreplace) %attr(0644,root,root) /usr/lib/systemd/system/my-app.service`

Is there some trick to make it non config?

Comment: I found workaround. It works for me, but looks ugly: `linuxPackageMappings in Rpm := {
            val before = (linuxPackageMappings in Rpm).value

            val after = before.find(_.mappings.exists(_._2.contains(".service"))).fold(before){mapping =>
                before.filter(_ != mapping) :+ mapping.withConfig("false")
            }
            after
        } `